# How to modify divs generated by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Complete noob question here:

I have this 16x16 grid of divs generated by jQuery

```js
var rows = 16;
var columns = 16;
var $row = $("<div />", {
  class: 'row'
});
var $square = $("<div />", {
  class: 'square'
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    $row.append($square.clone());
  }

  for (var x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
    $(".box_main").append($row.clone());
  }
});
```

```css
.row {
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
  background: #313131;
}
.square {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Can I somehow use the addClass and removeClass (or anything else) in order to change the background-color of each div one by one upon hovering/mouseenter over them?

I tried work something out but I'm not even sure whether it's possible or not to do this.

Comment: Yes you can use css classes to change the styling of your `div`s. You might want to try it for yourself first before asking. ;)

Comment: This is easy with jQuery, but easier with CSS. Make a new style with selector ```.square:hover``` and set the background color there.

Comment: I tried but I'm not even sure which element to select? Everytime I did something the grid just disappeared.

Answer (score 4):

`addClass()`/`removeClass()` (or even JS) is not needed for this - you can achieve it using the `:hover` pseduo selector of CSS alone. Try this:

```
.square:hover {
  background: #C00; /* amend colour as needed */
}
```

Working example:

```js
var rows = 16;
var columns = 16;
var $row = $("<div />", {
  class: 'row'
}).appendTo('body');
var $square = $("<div />", {
  class: 'square'
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    $row.append($square.clone());
  }

  for (var x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
    $(".box_main").append($row.clone());
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #313131;
}
.row {
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
  background: #313131;
}
.square {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
}
.square:hover {
  background: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thansk for that I'm not sure if :hover can be used if I wanted different colors for example for different buttons?

Comment: It can be made to work, but I'd need more details about the logic which governs which colours should be used on which elements. I'd suggest you start a new question with those details.

Answer (score 1):

beside the `:hover` pseduo selector, you might need to add an actual class to it with JS (perhaps it would make more sense if triggered by other event), nevertheless, here is an example using JS (addClass/removeClass)

```js
var rows = 16;
var columns = 16;
var $row = $("<div />", {
  class: 'row'
});
var $square = $("<div />", {
  class: 'square'
});
$row.appendTo('body');

$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    $row.append($square.clone());
  }

  for (var x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
    $(".box_main").append($row.clone());
  }

  $('.square').hover(function() { $(this).addClass('hovering'); }, function() { $(this).removeClass('hovering'); });
});
```

```css
.row {
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #313131;
}
.square {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.hovering {
  background-color: cyan;
  border: 3px dashed blue;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The hovering works but what if I want it to work something like a "drawing"? I think I asked the wrong question *facepalm